# npm cflags for node-odbc on OS X

Tags: node.js, node-odbc

Installing node-odbc on Linux is fine but on OS X it fails to find the include files:

cflags in binding.gyp is set to '-g', '-I/PATH_TO_UNIXODBC/include'

but it fails to find anything:

../src/odbc.h:29:10: fatal error: 'sql.h' file not found

sql.h exists in /PATH_TO_UNIXODBC/include

Answer (score 1):

Same here. It expect the header files in /usr/include folder.

I try to set CFLAG, but it also does not work. After that I installed unixodbc via brew which work now.
It would be great if some know how to setup using port.